# Why summing native lists is slower than summing church-encoded lists with `GHC -O2`?

Tags: algorithm, performance, list, haskell

In order to test how church-encoded lists perform against user-defiend lists and native lists, I've prepared 3 benchmarks:

#### User-defined lists

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) | Nil deriving Show
lenumTil n        = go n Nil where
    go 0 result   = result
    go n result   = go (n-1) (Cons (n-1) result)
lsum Nil          = 0
lsum (Cons h t)   = h + (lsum t)

main = print (lsum (lenumTil (100000000 :: Int)))
```

#### Native lists

```
main = print $ sum ([0..100000000-1] :: [Int])
```

#### Church lists

```
fsum   = (\ a -> (a (+) 0))
fenumTil n cons nil = go n nil where
    go 0 result    = result
    go n result    = go (n-1) (cons (n-1) result)
main = print $ (fsum (fenumTil (100000000 :: Int)) :: Int)
```

The benchmark results are unexpected:

#### User-defined lists

```
-- 4999999950000000
-- real 0m22.520s
-- user 0m59.815s
-- sys  0m20.327s
```

#### Native Lists

```
-- 4999999950000000
-- real 0m0.999s
-- user 0m1.357s
-- sys  0m0.252s
```

#### Church Lists

```
-- 4999999950000000
-- real 0m0.010s
-- user 0m0.002s
-- sys  0m0.003s
```

One would expect that, with the huge amount of specific optimizations targeted to native lists, they would perform the best. Yet, church lists outperform them by a 100x factor, and outperform user-defined ADTs by a 2250x factor. I've compiled all programs with `GHC -O2`. I've tried replacing `sum` by `foldl'`, same result. I've attempted adding user-inputs to make sure the church-list version wasn't optimized to a constant. `arkeet` pointed out on #haskell that, by inspecting Core, the native version has an intermediate lists, but why? Forcing allocation with an additional `reverse`, all 3 perform roughly the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "all 3 perform roughly the same"?

Comment: Not relevant, but... :  `go 0 result` should be `result (+) nil ` (right?)

Comment: Can you post the corresponding Core? (I.e., if it isn't absolutely gigantic.)

Comment: For what it's worth, on my machine your native list version takes 0.76s on GHC 7.6.3 and GHC 7.8.4, but only 0.05s on GHC 7.10.1. The Church version takes about 0.06s on all three.

Comment: (Oh, and the custom list version is dog slow on all three. But considering that it's not written in the same guarded recursive style that the other two are, that's pretty understandable.)

Comment: @JuanLopes no less than 3x slower.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I'm not well versed in Core, it is giving me something giant. What should I do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

GHC 7.10 has [call arity](http://www.joachim-breitner.de/publications/CallArity-TFP.pdf) analysis, which lets us define `foldl` in terms of `foldr` and thus let left folds, including `sum`, participate in fusion. GHC 7.8 also defines `sum` with `foldl` but it can't fuse the lists away. Thus GHC 7.10 performs optimally and identically to the Church version.

The Church version is child's play to optimize in either GHC versions. We just have to inline `(+)` and `0` into `fenumTil`, and then we have a patently tail-recursive `go` which can be readily unboxed and then turned into a loop by the code generator.

The user-defined version is not tail-recursive and it works in linear space, which wrecks performance, of course.

Comment: Omitted GHC Core because it doesn't show us anything interesting beyond what I wrote above.

Comment: I would like to see it :( but okay! Thanks András, I know someone would have the answer.

Comment: Eh, are you sure it is compiled to a loop? The executable works even for really, really huge numbers. Looks like it is compiled to the sum formula... (?)

Comment: (Maybe LLVM itself is compiling the loop to the formula, though?)

Comment: @Viclib Computers are really good at adding big numbers. They are bad at storing a big number of numbers.